# Найти Label по Content и удалить его

Tags: c#, wpf

Как программно можно найти дочерние элементы `Label` по их `Content` внутри `Canvas` и удалить их ? Создаются динамически и по ненадобности нужно удалять по их `Content`

Comment: В WPF? Удалить Label? Вы серьезно?!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ куда серьёзнее было бы, помочь мне понять что не так...

Comment: `myCanvas.Children.OfType<Label>().Where(l=>l.Content is MyContent).ToArray()`?

Comment: @Vipz Евгений этим вопросом намекает на то, что ты как-то неправильно понимаешь концепцию WPF и тебе явно нужно залепить пробелы в знании концепции. Он намекает что сам вопрос показывает непонимание того как работать с WPF правильно в принципе.... И он... прав... Ты где-то пошел не в ту сторону и нужно было бы начать изучать WPF с нуля что бы понять почему ты пошел не в ту сторону и где именно :) А вот **Tym** просто дал решение проигнорировав неправильное понимание концепций. Но, я советую последовать совету Евгения... И начать изучить как работать с WPF правильно...

Comment: @Andrew, зато от комментария Тима автору вопроса есть польза, в отличии от Вашего и Евгения. Он не концепциями интересуется, а конкретной проблемой.

Comment: @tym32167 ругается на MyContent "Требуется постоянное значение"

Comment: @Vipz, очевидно, что `MyContent` это то, по чему Вы должны искать.

Comment: @ixSci Вот придете вы к врачу с больным зубом и скажете ему "Вырвите, он меня уже замучал". Врач возьмет, да вырвет, ибо вы так просили, но если бы был нормальный врач, то он бы сказал "Данный зуб можно спасти" и занялся бы им. Так и тут, решений одной задачи - уйма и не все из них хорошие. WPF - это в первую очередь привязки и работа с ними, а создание контролов через код - это издевательство над самим собой и WPF в целом. Так может человек просто не знает как правильно работать? И может тогда его стоит направить в правильное русло? Чем давать ему то, что он хочет...

Comment: @ixSci оба коментария полезны. Один ответил на четко поставленный вопрос, но в то же время несет вред т.к. у человека поощряется неправильная работа с инструментом и человек не развивается в правильном направлении. Коментарий полезный лишь в короткой перспективе. Другой же коментарий говорит что нужно задуматся о том, что ты не умеешь работать с инструментом правильно. Он бесполезен в короткой перспективе, но очень полезен в долгой перспективе. При чем полезность в долгой перспективе просто загранична :)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Ваша аналогия неуместна. Каким образом Ваш первый комментарий куда-то направил? Нечего сказать по теме или не хотите отвечать — проходите мимо. И перечитайте правила этого ресурса заодно, а также его цель. Andrew, Вас это тоже касается. Это ресурс вопросов и ответов, а не отвлечённых рассуждений. P.S. Про работу с контролами через код: Вам фамилия Петцольд о чём-то говорит? Если да, то рекомендую заглянуть в его книгу по WPF и поискать там XAML.

Comment: @ixSci Почему не уместна, полностью показывает текущую ситуацию. Куда направил мой первый комментарий? Хм, ну наверно он рассчитан на то, что бы понять к чему стремиться автор и какие у него на данный момент навыки. Все для дальнейшего написания полноценного, правильного ответа. Можете прочитать любой мой комментарий на SO - я всегда выхожу на эти ответы и подобный комментарий дает мне знать, интересно ли вообще это автору или нет. Правила? Хм, вы серьезно? И что же я такое нарушаю, что вы меня туда посылаете? Я не в праве задавать наводящие вопросы? В общем давайте каждый останется при своем.